# How do I write to a python file from a multi-line input received in a gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Im writing a program that's meant to help me with work, but getting stuck on setting up a gui that will receive user input and then use that input to write python code into a file named config.py

config.py is based off of 5 classes that have multiple lines of text each that function as quicknotes that are written to a separate frame in the gui. I need a user-friendly way to edit these classes instead of opening my text editor (atom in this case) and writing my quicknotes into python code.

I have the gui set up to receive a text panel for which quicknote is being edited, a text panel for the title, and a multi-line text panel for the actual notes. However, because I'm doing the user input insertion into config.py manually, anytime more than one line is put into the body, its no longer formatted correctly

My configGUI.py is the file that is grabbing the user input and writing to the config.py file and here is the code for that

```
qnBody_label = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Quicknote Text')
self.body_Control = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
widgets.append(qnBody_label)
widgets.append(self.body_Control)

qnTitle_label = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Quicknote Title')
self.title_Control = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
widgets.append(qnTitle_label)
widgets.append(self.title_Control)

qnBody_label = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Quicknote Text')
self.body_Control = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
widgets.append(qnBody_label)
widgets.append(self.body_Control)

quicknoteNumber = "class QN%s():" % self.number_Control.GetValue()
quicknoteTitle = "\ttitle = '%s'" % self.title_Control.GetValue()
quicknoteBody = "\tnote = (\n\t'%s'\n)" % self.body_Control.GetValue()
```

Here is an example of what im expecting in config.py:

```
class QN1():
    title = "Heres the title"
    note = (
        'First line of quicknotes\n'
        'Heres some more notes\n'
        'And the last notes\n'
    )
```

what I actually receive is:

```
class QN1():
    title = "Heres the title"
    note = (
        'First line of quicknotes
Heres some more notes
And the last notes'
    )
```

which makes sense given what im telling it to do, but im unsure of how to grab input from a multi-line text panel and format it into python correctly

Comment: Process each line in self.body_Control separately, adding in the tab \t characters as appropriate. `split` should do the job for you, as in `lines = self.body_Control.GetValue().split("\n")`

Comment: Rolf, that definitely helps, but the \n in the split doesnt actually do a newline or print the \n into the file, I did some more research and tried hashtag and because of the definition of my quicnoteBody, theres a \n that prints after every instance. Now the only issue im running into is that there are brackets before and after the list, which is causing the list to not print. I did further research to see if I could remove the brackets but its expecting a string, but getting a list instead and giving me an error

Comment: `split` removes the delimiter that you are spliting on, so if you need it, you will need to add it back in as you process each of the items in the list in your `for item in list` statement then use `"\n\t\t"+item+"\n"` or whatever fits your purpose to build the text that will be written to the file. Note: there is an alternative to `split`, namely `.splitlines(keepends=True)` that splits on a newline and returns the newline with the text into the `list`

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the new line, it is behaving exactly as it should, it prints it on a  new line, what you need to do is format it yourself by adding the spaces yourself after the \n. Add \t as that is a short version for tab

Comment: Thats my question though, is that I want to change my program so that it does it itself. I know my program is working as intended how its written now, but im asking advice on changing it so that it adds the newline and tabs it in with ' ' every new line in the multiline text panel. Sorry if I didnt make that clear